# OpenSAML (2.0) EntitiesDescriptor signature validation not working

Tags: java, validation, opensaml

I have no clue how to log a bug to the Shibboleth project, so I'll write some findings I've come across with OpenSAML signature validation. There is an issue related to the way OpenSAML (2.0) attempts to validate signatures in SAML metadata (EntitiesDescriptor).

I was trying to desperately validate the signature in my SAML metadata structure with FilesystemMetadataProvider, however it throws me NullPointerException always. There are some other articles about this issue elsewhere, but nobody seemed to know about the exact reason for it.

Now what I first tried was something like this:

```
FilesystemMetadataProvider provider = new FilesystemMetadataProvider(new File("metadata.xml"));
provider.setRequireValidMetadata(true);
provider.setParserPool(new BasicParserPool());
provider.initialize();
EntitiesDescriptor ed = provider.getEntitiesDescriptor("My Servers");
SignatureValidator validator = new SignatureValidator(getTrustedCredential());
validator.validate(ed.getSignature());
```

This constantly ends up throwing an exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException at org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator.validate(SignatureValidator.java:69)

After some debugging around XMLTooling and OpenSAML classes, I found a reason for the error. The problem seems to be in the way the XMLSignature is handled in org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.SignatureImpl class:

```
public void releaseDOM() {
  super.releaseDOM();
  **this.xmlSignature = null;**
  if (this.keyInfo != null) {
    this.keyInfo.releaseChildrenDOM(true);
    this.keyInfo.releaseDOM();
  }
}

public XMLSignature getXMLSignature() {
  return this.xmlSignature;
}

public void setXMLSignature(XMLSignature signature) {
  this.xmlSignature = ((XMLSignature)prepareForAssignment(this.xmlSignature, signature));
}
```

Now the SignatureValidator runs these methods in order setXMLSignature() --> releaseDOM() --> getXMLSignature() which fails to validate EntitiesDescriptor. However, with other signature types this seems to work okay.

As a workaround there were two ways I managed to validate the signature:

1) Reverse engineering the SignatureImpl class and removing "this.xmlSignature = null;" from releaseDOM() method

2) Reimplementing signature validation using XML parsing and unmarshalling (shown below)

```
File file = new File("metadata.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.parse(file);
UnmarshallerFactory unmarshallerFactory = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory();
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = unmarshallerFactory.getUnmarshaller(document.getDocumentElement());
EntitiesDescriptor ed = (EntitiesDescriptor) unmarshaller.unmarshall(document.getDocumentElement());
SignatureValidator validator = new SignatureValidator(getTrustedCredential());
validator.validate(ed.getSignature());
```

Anybody else seen this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How to file bugs et al: https://shibboleth.net/community/

You don't need to reverse-engineer it, OpenSAML source is available: http://svn.shibboleth.net/view/java-opensaml2/trunk/src

OpenSAML source repo has unit tests that cover most of their code base. This is where you can learn how to use the library. For example, signature validation on metadata is encapsulated into SignatureValidationFilter class. Here's a unit test that shows you how to use it: http://svn.shibboleth.net/view/java-opensaml2/trunk/src/test/java/org/opensaml/saml2/metadata/provider/SignatureValidationFilterTest.java

From this unit test you can see that they're using SAMLSignatureProfileValidator as the implementation of Validator. It is more sophisticated than plain SignatureValidator.

Try SignatureValidationFilter. If it still doesn't work, post your metadata here.